# How to run "the super tiny compiler"?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, github, compiler-construction, setup-project

https://github.com/jamiebuilds/the-super-tiny-compiler

I've imported this project in Eclipse. When I compile and run "the-super-tiny-compiler.js", it gets terminated instantly. Why doesn't it asks us to input the source code, and why doesn't it show the compiled output? Is something missing in this code?

Comment: You don't compile JS code

Comment: @Luca Can you please tell me, how do I make it run in Eclipse?

Comment: You need to run it with node.js as it states on the homepage.

Comment: @csmckelvey I already did. Running "test.js" with node prints "All passed!", which is expected by reading the code. Whereas, "the-super-tiny-compiler.js" terminates just after running it. Console window neither prompts to enter anything, nor prints anything.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "main" code in there or any code to read a source file (or read from stdin). Only a function that takes the source as a string.

So it looks like it's meant as a library and you'll have to write your own IO code if you want to turn it into a command line application.

Alternatively you could use it from an HTML page and get the source from a textarea.